# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: 26 in my code when i try to run certain letters (e) and i dont know how to resolve it.

The array contains 26 characters(each letter of the alphabet). Can anybody see the problem in the code?

```
//Breaking up the letters from the input and placing them in an array
char[] plaintext = input.toCharArray();
//For loops that will match length of input against alphabet and move the letter 14 spaces
for(int i = 0;i<plaintext.length;i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j<25;j++) {
        if(j<=12 && plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]) {
            plaintext[i] = alphabet[j+14];
            break;
        }
        //Else if the input letter is near the end of the alphabet then reset back to the start of the alphabet
        else if(plaintext[i] == alphabet[j]) {
            plaintext[i] = alphabet [j-26];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays start at 0. If it contains 26 entrys it will be in range 0-25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(j<=12 && plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]) {
     plaintext[i] = alphabet[j+14];
     break;
}
```

This code will access `alphabet[26]` if `j == 12` and `plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]`. Your array has indexes **0-25**. Java arrays have zero based indexes.

Comment: Thanks, the encryption is now working but now the decryption is giving the wrong output after the 14th letter. What do I need to change? ive updated the code for decrytion above.

Comment: @d99 This is a totally different question. Please accept **any** answer here, they are all more or less equally helpful. Then try to solve it yourself. After that, ask another question **if needed**.

Comment: Sorry, I tried it myself but cant really find what's wrong and I thought it would be relevant. I've accepted your answer, thanks.

Comment: No worries, but I recommend you to carefully think through your solution and possibly try a different approach. You will learn a lot more that way, and end up a better coder. :)

Answer (score 3):

If it contains 26 characters (as you said) then the last index is 25 not 26. That causes the problem.

You have `j<=12` so when `j` is 12 then you have index 26 (`j+14`) and that is out of array.

Answer (score 3):

You have the edge case where `j == 12` and you dereference `alphabet[j+14]` == `alphabet[26]`.

Answer (score 3):

When `j` is 12, you'll get **26**. Since arrays in Java are *zero-based* arrays, your array indexes are from 0 to 25, so 26 is outOfBounds.

```
  if(j<=12 && plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]){
     //Check if j+14 doesn't exceed 25
```

Another thing, your for loops should be `for(int j = 0 ; j<26;j++){` (don't worry, 25 is the last index).

BTW, the exception you're getting is very informative. Using a debugger will help a lot in cases like this.